# Why is my paralax not working with my dropdown menu code, HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using one html file for my website i'm building but i am using two stylesheet files. One CSS contains a paralax and without the dropdown code added it works fine, the other CSS file contains all the code for the dropdown menu which i took from a free code snippet site just too practise.

How can i combine both or get them to work properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown_menu.css">

    <title> My portforlio </title>

    <input class="dark-light" type="checkbox" id="dark-light" name="dark-light"/>
    <label for="dark-light"></label>

    <div class="light-back"></div> 

  

    <div class="sec-center">    
        <input class="dropdown" type="checkbox" id="dropdown" name="dropdown"/>
        <label class="for-dropdown" for="dropdown">Dropdown Menu <i class="uil uil-arrow-down"></i></label>
        <div class="section-dropdown"> 
            <a href="#">Dropdown Link <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
            <input class="dropdown-sub" type="checkbox" id="dropdown-sub" name="dropdown-sub"/>
            <label class="for-dropdown-sub" for="dropdown-sub">Dropdown Sub <i class="uil uil-plus"></i></label>
            <div class="section-dropdown-sub"> 
                <a href="#">Dropdown Link <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
                <a href="#">Dropdown Link <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#">Dropdown Link <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
            <a href="#">Dropdown Link <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>


    </head>
<body>
    


    <div class ="margin"></div>
    
    <section class ="parallax">
        <div class ="parallax-inner">
            <h1 style="color:white;"><center>JAMES HAYZEN</h1>
            
        </div>
    </section>
    

    <div class ="margin"></div>






</body>
"the first css file"
</html>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0; 


}
.margin {
    margin: 75% 0;
}
.parallax {
    background: url("bg1.jpg")
    repeat fixed 100%;
}
.parallax-inner {
    padding-top: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
}

body {
    font-family: calibri, arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 60px;
```

"this is the second css file"

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap');

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1f2029;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/pat-back.svg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 4%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}
.sec-center {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 200;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked){
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dark-light:checked + label,
.dark-light:not(:checked) + label{
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 20000;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(255,235,167,.45);
}
.dark-light:checked + label{
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.dark-light:checked + label:after,
.dark-light:not(:checked) + label:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #102770;
  background-image: url('https://assets.codepen.io/1462889/moon.svg');
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
.dark-light:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.dark-light:checked + label:before,
.dark-light:not(:checked) + label:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  background-color: #48dbfb;
  background-image: url('https://assets.codepen.io/1462889/sun.svg');
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.dark-light:checked + label:before{
  background-color: #000;
}
.light-back{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/pat-back.svg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 4%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
.dark-light:checked ~ .light-back{
  opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown:checked + label,
.dropdown:not(:checked) + label{
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 2;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 220px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffeba7;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #102770;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 35px 0 rgba(255,235,167,.15);
}
.dark-light:checked ~ .sec-center .for-dropdown{
  background-color: #102770;
  color: #ffeba7;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 35px 0 rgba(16,39,112,.25);
}
.dropdown:checked + label:before,
.dropdown:not(:checked) + label:before{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dropdown:checked + label:before{
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.dropdown:not(:checked) + label .uil {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
}
.dropdown:checked + label .uil {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
}
.section-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #111;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 35px 0 rgba(9,9,12,0.4);
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.dark-light:checked ~ .sec-center .section-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 35px 0 rgba(9,9,12,0.15);
}
.dropdown:checked ~ .section-dropdown{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.section-dropdown:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
.section-dropdown:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 8px solid #111;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.dark-light:checked ~ .sec-center .section-dropdown:after {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #fff;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
}
.dark-light:checked ~ .sec-center .section-dropdown a {
  color: #102770;
}
a:hover {
  color: #102770;
  background-color: #ffeba7;
}
.dark-light:checked ~ .sec-center .section-dropdown a:hover {
  color: #ffeba7;
  background-color: #102770;
}
a .uil {
  font-size: 22px;
}
.dropdown-sub:checked + label,
.dropdown-sub:not(:checked) + label{
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-sub:checked + label .uil,
.dropdown-sub:not(:checked) + label .uil{
  font-size: 22px;
}
.dropdown-sub:not(:checked) + label .uil {
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
}
.dropdown-sub:checked + label .uil {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
}
.dropdown-sub:checked + label:hover,
.dropdown-sub:not(:checked) + label:hover{
  color: #102770;
  background-color: #ffeba7;
}
.dark-light:checked ~ .sec-center .section-dropdown .for-dropdown-sub{
  color: #102770;
}
.dark-light:checked ~ .sec-center .section-dropdown .for-dropdown-sub:hover{
  color: #ffeba7;
  background-color: #102770;
}

.section-dropdown-sub {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.dropdown-sub:checked ~ .section-dropdown-sub{
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 999px;
}
.section-dropdown-sub a {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.section-dropdown-sub a .uil {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 40px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 11000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
    transition: all 250ms linear;
}
.logo:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.logo img {
    height: 26px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.dark-light:checked ~ .logo img{
  filter: brightness(10%);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
.logo {
    top: 30px;
    left: 20px;
}
.dark-light:checked + label,
.dark-light:not(:checked) + label{
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
}
```

Tried putting the link files in the head and the body but get the same error

Comment: you see that you have some rules `*` and `body` for example that are in both files and with different rules? this is causing the issue. The second css overwrites the first and this means that some rules that are required by the parallax effect are overwritten by those of the dropdown

Comment: try to understand how to merge the conflicting rules or try to change the dropdown css to something that is not impacting the whole dom css

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown_menu.css">
        <title> My portforlio </title>
      
    </head>
    <body>
     
      <input class="dark-light" type="checkbox" id="dark-light" name="dark-light"/>
      <label for="dark-light"></label>
    
      <div class="light-back"></div> 
      <div class="sec-center">  
        
        <input class="dropdown" type="checkbox" id="dropdown" name="dropdown"/>
        <label class="for-dropdown" for="dropdown">Dropdown Menu <i class="uil uil-arrow-down"></i></label>
        
         <div class="section-dropdown"> 
                <a href="#">Dropdown Link <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
                <input class="dropdown-sub" type="checkbox" id="dropdown-sub" name="dropdown-sub"/>
                <label class="for-dropdown-sub" for="dropdown-sub">Dropdown Sub <i class="uil uil-plus"></i></label>
                <div class="section-dropdown-sub"> 
                    <a href="#">Dropdown Link <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
                    <a href="#">Dropdown Link <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Dropdown Link <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
                <a href="#">Dropdown Link <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class ="margin"></div>
        
      <section class ="parallax">
        <div class ="parallax-inner">
           <h1><center>JAMES HAYZEN</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div class ="margin"></div>
      "the first css file"
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

In `<head>` element contains meta information about the HTML page.

In  `<body>` element defines the document's body and is a container for all the visible contents, such as headings, paragraphs, images, hyperlinks, tables, lists, etc.

Comment: While those are true statements, HTML rules of error recovery mean it doesn't make any practical difference.

Comment: So i should move the link statements to the body?